# Unable to generate AAD Token using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I have to embed power BI report using service principle in my java application. so i am trying to generate AAD access token. But I fail to generate access token. Below is the code and output. I have tried to generate aad access token using Javascript also but could not do so. Please help.

## Find my code here

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationCallback;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;


public class GenerateToken {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Connecting to Azure......");

        System.out.println("AAD Token" + ServicePrinciple.getAADAccessTokenFromAzure().get().getAccessToken());
    }
}

final class ServicePrinciple {

    static String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/token";
    static String clientId = "";
    static String clientSecret = "";
    static String resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

    private static Future<AuthenticationResult> getAADAccessToken(String authority, String resource, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
        AuthenticationCallback callback = null;
        ClientCredential clientCredential = null;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        try {
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, executorService);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Future<AuthenticationResult> authenticationResult = context.acquireToken(resource, clientCredential, callback);
        return authenticationResult;
    }

    static Future<AuthenticationResult> getAADAccessTokenFromAzure() {
        return getAADAccessToken(authority, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
    }

}
```

## Output of my code

```
Connecting to Azure......
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority - [Correlation ID: 9f8f9bde-fc94-4cb9-bf91-1a3ef2e79d10] Instance discovery was successful
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: 9f8f9bde-fc94-4cb9-bf91-1a3ef2e79d10] Request to acquire token failed.
java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:726)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:128)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.inetpsa.spd.raloyalty.action.GenerateToken.main(GenerateToken.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:726)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:128)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same code working (for the last day or so)

However my code snippet look like the folowing

```
String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant id}";
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
```

Are you behind a firewall that isn't allowing you reach login.microsoftonline.com?

You can use the following API page to login and generate a report token
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup

Answer (score 0):

is your login.microsoftonline.com behind a proxy? if so, set your proxy with the either set of jvm arguments depending if it is http or https:

HTTPS
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy-name-without-https.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxy-port
ex. -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=2021

or

HTTP
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy-name-without-http.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy-port
ex. -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=2021